# Display menu on hover reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, reactstrap

In a react application, I am using reactstrap css framework to make the dropdowns to list the dropdown menus.

**Example.Js**

```
      <Dropdown
        className="d-inline-block"
        onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
        isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen}
        toggle={this.toggle}
      >
        <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown1</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem header>Submenu 1</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Submenu 1.1</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown2</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem header>Submenu 2</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.1</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.2</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <br /><br />
        <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown3</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          <DropdownItem header>Submenu 3</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.1</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.2</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.3</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
```

Here I have made the `setState` to set the state for `dropDownOpen` in the events such as `onMouseOver` and  `onMouseLeave`.

The **issue** is on hover of single dropdown menu, every dropdown gets opened.

[**Click here for Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-v6-uhyfcl)

Kindly help me to make the hover dropdown to only list the menus of hovered one and **not all** at a time.

**Note:** In my real application, these dropdown menus will be dynamic, So I cant make any hardcoded state like, `dropDown1`, `dropDown2`, `dropDown3` ... etc ..

It may have any `n` number of dropdowns.. So please give me solution in keeping the dynamic menus into consideration.

Comment: All the dropdown toggles and menus are within a single dropdown, controlled by a single state variable. I think each should be in their own `Dropdown` component.

Comment: for both three drop downs you are using the same state

Comment: @DrewReese, I am new in reactjs, So can you help me in giving right solution for it by modifing the above given example? Please feel free to edit my example and provide good solution for this problem.. I may be wrong in the approach so please correct me..

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, I am new in reactjs, So can you help me in giving right solution for it by modifing the above given example?

Comment: @TestUser Sure i will update with new stackblitz

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, Please feel free to edit my example and provide good solution for this problem.. I may be wrong in the approach so please correct me..

Comment: Before that let me conclude your requirements, so you have n number of dropdowns and hovering on each dropdown the only one should be expanded and should show the options. Any thing else is there apart from it.

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, Yes that is all about.. The menus of hovered one should be displayed separately..

Comment: @TestUser Sure i will update and let you know

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, Any update from your end?

Comment: @TestUser I was little bc, i will update give me some time

Comment: @TestUser check this one, if its fine i will add it as the answer https://codesandbox.io/s/59574892-so-n-number-of-dropdowns-9hkt3

Comment: @TestUser Handling `n` root dropdowns is fairly trivial, but how dynamic is the nesting of submenus? Will they have further submenus? Can you provide an example of the data source driving the menus?

Comment: @DrewReese, I have said ```n``` dropdown bcoz the solution which you give had numbers such as ```dropDown1```, ```dropDown2```, ```dropDown3``` which is not my expectation, Some time I may have some ```n``` numbers and sometimes different ```n``` numbers so we cannot have exact count..

Comment: @DrewReese, Submenus wont have multiple submenus.. Take a look at https://www.supply.com/ this is exactly how my menus look like.. I am trying to achieve the horizontal menu like this one.. This is how my real app dropdowns will be looking like.

Answer (score 1):

Basically each dropdown menu needs to be in its own `Dropdown` composite component, with its own state and handlers. I forked and updated your demo that hopefully gives you the right idea.

```
<div>
    <Dropdown
      className="d-inline-block"
      onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
      isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen1}
      toggle={this.toggle1}
    >
      <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown1</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Submenu 1</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Submenu 1.1</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </Dropdown>
    <Dropdown
      className="d-inline-block"
      // onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter}
      // onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
      isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen2}
      toggle={this.toggle2}
    >

      <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown2</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Submenu 2</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.1</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.2</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <br /><br />

    </Dropdown>
    <Dropdown
      className="d-inline-block"
      // onMouseOver={this.onMouseEnter}
      // onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
      isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen3}
      toggle={this.toggle3}
    >

      <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown3</DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Submenu 3</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.1</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.2</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.3</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </Dropdown>
  </div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-v6-2dnzex?file=Example.js

Comment: Whether there is no optimum way of doing it? Here in your example you have repeated the toggle 3 times to make this work but is there no way to make it in a single state? I am strictly following DRY(Don't Repeat Yourself) method, So in review this code will be ignored..

Comment: And also every menu should be displayed on hover.. Why you have modified 2 and 3rd dropdown it to on click? Everything should be on hover and handled separately..

Comment: You could try making your own wrapped version of `Dropdown` that internalizes the state and handlers then compose your menus. This was a quick and dirty to show how to split out the menu items so they weren't locked/driven by a single variable.

Comment: What would be the solution here if the dropdown menus comes in ```n``` numbers as dynamic one??

Comment: `n` menus wasn't part of your original question, mate. You could use an array of toggle and hover state values and use the index to access. Simply push new handlers in for each new menu you add.

Comment: You can provide me right solution by changing the entire approach of mine but keeping things in reactstrap alone.. I am making this in an application where the menus will be dynamic so I cannot give like this ```dropdown1```, ```dropdown2```, ```dropdown3```.. Hope you understand my situation.. Please feel free to post new answer..

Comment: Hey no worries. Please amend your question and list out requirements and/or restraints on your code, and what your expected result should be. It's much easier to design when you know what the specs are. Try to be as specific and detailed as possible.

Comment: Yes it is not part of my question but that was my real app scenario.. Even here in dropdown 2 and 3 it was clickable in yours which is not intended.. If we think in user perspective, do you think will it be the right one?

Comment: Hi @TestUser and Drew Reese I have reduces some line using arrow functions: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-dropdown?file=Example.js and if you need this for n dropdown then you can create single drop-down and using props you can create multiple dropdown for this, that is the beauty for react.

Comment: @DrewReese, Did you get any chance to look into better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to show the submenu of the menu or dropdown.
Feel free to ask any questions or if you have any confusion about it.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Box, jsx } from 'theme-ui';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';
import { H1 } from '../../components/ThemeHeader';
import { Image } from '../../components';

const CardWithCTALinks = (props) => {
  const { cardWithCTALinksImage, ctaLinks, heading, bgColor } = props;
  const [onCTAListHover, setOnCTAListHover] = React.useState({ status: '', indexAt: -1 });

  const updateCTAListHover = (newOnCTAListHover, idx) => {
    if (newOnCTAListHover !== onCTAListHover) setOnCTAListHover({ state: newOnCTAListHover, indexAt: idx });
  };
  const renderImageSection = (src, alt) => {
    return <Image src={src} alt={alt} />;
  };
  const renderSubLinks = (subLinks, idx) => {
    return (
      <Box>
        {idx === onCTAListHover.indexAt &&
          subLinks.map((link) => (
            <Link key={Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)} to="/">
              {link.text}
            </Link>
          ))}
      </Box>
    );
  };
  const renderLinksSection = (linksList, headingText) => {
    return (
      <Box>
        {headingText && <H1>{headingText}</H1>}
        {linksList && (
          <Box>
            {linksList.map((link, index) => (
              <h1 onMouseEnter={() => updateCTAListHover(true, index)} onMouseLeave={() => updateCTAListHover(false, index)}>
                {link.node?.title}
                {link.node?.navItems.length > 0 && <>{onCTAListHover && renderSubLinks(link.node?.navItems, index)}</>}
              </h1>
            ))}
          </Box>
        )}
      </Box>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Box style={{ backgroundColor: bgColor }}>
      {cardWithCTALinksImage && <Box>{renderImageSection(cardWithCTALinksImage?.asset._ref, 'alt')}</Box>}
      {ctaLinks && heading && <Box>{renderLinksSection(ctaLinks.edges, heading)}</Box>}
    </Box>
  );
};

export default CardWithCTALinks;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import React from "react";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.onMouseEnter = this.onMouseEnter.bind(this);
    this.onMouseLeave = this.onMouseLeave.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen1: false,
      dropdownOpen2: false,
      dropdownOpen3: false
    };
  }

  toggle(id) {
   this.setState({[id]:!this.state[`${id}`]})
  }

  onMouseEnter(id) {
    this.setState({ [id]: true });
  }

  onMouseLeave(id) {
    this.setState({ [id]: false });

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dropdown
          className="d-inline-block"
          onMouseOver={()=>this.onMouseEnter("dropdownOpen1")}
          onMouseLeave={()=>this.onMouseLeave("dropdownOpen1")}
          isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen1}
          toggle={()=>this.toggle("dropdownOpen1")}
        >
          <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown1</DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownItem header>Submenu 1</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Submenu 1.1</DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
        <Dropdown
          className="d-inline-block"
           onMouseOver={()=>this.onMouseEnter("dropdownOpen2")}
          onMouseLeave={()=>this.onMouseLeave("dropdownOpen2")}
          isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen2}
          toggle={()=>this.toggle("dropdownOpen2")}
        >
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown2</DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownItem header>Submenu 2</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.1</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Submenu 2.2</DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown>
        <Dropdown
          className="d-inline-block"
        onMouseOver={()=>this.onMouseEnter("dropdownOpen3")}
          onMouseLeave={()=>this.onMouseLeave("dropdownOpen3")}
          isOpen={this.state.dropdownOpen3}
          toggle={()=>this.toggle("dropdownOpen3")}
        >
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <br />
          <br />
          <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown3</DropdownToggle>
          <DropdownMenu>
            <DropdownItem header>Submenu 3</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.1</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.2</DropdownItem>
            <DropdownItem>Submenu 3.3</DropdownItem>
          </DropdownMenu>
        </Dropdown> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Try it out once !!!let me know,basically you need to pass different args for each dropdown ,so that your method can differentiate what to open or close.

Comment: you can make your DropDown dynamic based on what you are getting from source hit,then use map inside render to make everything dynamic!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @TestUser and Drew Reese I have reduces some line using arrow functions: https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactstrap-dropdown?file=Example.js and if you need this for n dropdown then you can create single drop-down and using props you can create multiple dropdown for this (you can use map for repeating for this) and can use this multiple places. that is the beauty of react.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you were using same state variable for all three dropdowns.

To fix this you need to maintain three different state variables, since you want to have dynamic way you can follow the below approach

Also for reusable approach you can make the Dropdown as a separate component.

You can add more logic if you want, this is the simple way to solve the problem

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Container } from "reactstrap";
import CustomDropDown from "./CustomDropdown";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

import "./styles.css";

const dropdownConfig = [
  {
    customKey: 1,
    options: [
      { title: "Submenu 1", header: true },
      { title: "Submenu 1.1", header: false }
    ],
    name: "dropdownOpen1"
  },
  {
    customKey: 2,
    options: [
      { title: "Submenu 2", header: true },
      { title: "Submenu 2.1", header: false }
    ],
    name: "dropdownOpen2"
  },
  {
    customKey: 3,
    options: [
      { title: "Submenu 3", header: true },
      { title: "Submenu 3.1", header: false }
    ],
    name: "dropdownOpen3"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [keysForDropdown, setKeysForDropdown] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const keys = dropdownConfig.map(dropdown => dropdown.name);
    const object = keys.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      acc[curr] = false;
      return acc;
    }, {});
    setKeysForDropdown({ ...object });
  }, []);

  const _handleToggle = e => {
    setKeysForDropdown({
      ...keysForDropdown,
      [e.target.name]: !keysForDropdown[e.target.name]
    });
  };

  const _handleMouseEnter = e => {
    setKeysForDropdown({
      ...keysForDropdown,
      [e.target.name]: !keysForDropdown[e.target.name]
    });
  };

  const _handleMouseLeave = e => {
    setKeysForDropdown({
      ...keysForDropdown,
      [e.target.name]: !keysForDropdown[e.target.name]
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Container>
        {keysForDropdown &&
          dropdownConfig.map(dropdown => (
            <CustomDropDown
              {...dropdown}
              key={dropdown.customKey}
              stateKeys={keysForDropdown}
              handleToggle={_handleToggle}
              handleMouseEnter={_handleMouseEnter}
              handleMouseLeave={_handleMouseLeave}
            />
          ))}
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

**CustomDropdown.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem
} from "reactstrap";

const CustomDropDown = props => {
  const {
    handleMouseEnter,
    handleMouseLeave,
    handleToggle,
    options,
    name,
    stateKeys
  } = props;
  return (
    <div className="dropdown-container">
      <Dropdown
        className="d-inline-block"
        onMouseOver={handleMouseEnter}
        onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
        isOpen={stateKeys[name]}
        toggle={handleToggle}
      >
        <DropdownToggle name={name} caret>
          Dropdown1
        </DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu>
          {options.length &&
            options.map(({ header, title }) => (
              <DropdownItem header={header}>{title}</DropdownItem>
            ))}
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomDropDown;
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59574892-so-n-number-of-dropdowns-9hkt3)

Comment: This solution works well, but has a bug where toggled open menus toggle off when hovered over. You should keep two states for each menu, `isOpen` and `isHovered` and set the `isOpen` prop on the component as the union of them. Something like `isOpen={stateKeys[name].isOpen || stateKeys[name].isHovered}`. This way one "state" won't override the other.

Comment: I got little confused @DrewReese, can you fork and update it

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS, Have a look into this link https://www.supply.com/, this is how my dropdown should be so on hover each one it should display the submenus and user can select from it.. This is how my real app dropdowns will be looking like. Consider only the horizontal dropdowns in this link..